# Oracle: find tables with open cursors

Tags: oracle, select

I need to select tables and id of session related to it. I found that Oracle has the V$OPEN_CURSOR view, but I can’t find a way to connect these cursors with their tables. The only queries I found were about the amount of currently opened cursors and the error about exceeding maximum number of cursors. Would be really grateful if you can lead me to some table, with which I could connect cursors with its tables. Or maybe there is some other way, thank you.

Comment: Привет! Sorry, It's not completely clear what do you exactly need to found? What do you mean by saying "select tables and id of session related to it". Can you get us an example perhaps?

Comment: Using the information from the data dictionary views, create a list of tables with currently open cursors within the specified schema. The received information should be presented in the form of a list in the following format:

No. Name of the table Session ID table
-— —-----------------------------— —-----------
1 PEOPLE 00000001
2 CHARACTERISTIC 00000002
3 STUDENTS 00000003
4 PLANS 00000005
5 DEPARTMENTS 00000004
...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment I suppose this is what you are looking for

```
select rownum, q.*
from  (select distinct p.object_name, c.sid
         from v$open_cursor c
         join V$SQL_PLAN p
           on p.sql_id = c.sql_id
        where p.object_type = 'TABLE'
        order by c.sid) q
```

It takes all the tables from the query plans for open cursor. The distinct is here to filter out all the tables opened twice in same query for same session.

The version below you need for debugging - it displays the full sql cursor is open for. Please note that "debug version" works much slower due to clob solumn

```
select distinct p.object_name, c.sid, s.SQL_FULLTEXT
  from v$open_cursor c
  join V$SQL_PLAN p
    on p.sql_id = c.sql_id
  join v$sql s
    on p.sql_id = s.sql_id
 where p.object_type = 'TABLE'
 order by c.sid;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! This seems like something I need, but my IDE shows that v$open_cursor doesn't have an attribute child_address. Did you mean SADDR or ADDRESS maybe ? I've tried them both but there were 0 rows found. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/dynviews_2081.htm#REFRN30166

Comment: @ДаниилДемичев I removed the joins on child_addres. You don't need them